# How to find the IP Address of Client connected to Server?

Tags: java, sockets, ip-address

My client pc is connected to as server pc via sockets over Ethernet, How do I find the IP of this client from the server side code.
The server is dishing out one socket per client in a new Thread.
When I do a `csocket.getLocalAddress().toString()` on the client socket I still get the Server IP address. (`csocket` is the socket that the Server has spawned upon a now client connection and passed it to a new Thread).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I believe you want to use the [remote address](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getRemoteSocketAddress%28%29) instead:

```
csocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
```

Comment: How Get client ip from HttpServer object? see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274828/get-client-ip-from-httpserver

Answer (score 14):

I think you might be looking for the [getInetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress--) method of the [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) object.

Comment: That gives the local address of the socket.  The server needs to find the remote address from its perspective.

Comment: @Stephen: according to the Javadoc, `getInetAddress()` "returns the remote IP address to which this socket is connected, or null if the socket is not connected."

Answer (score 6):

Use this code :

```
String ip=(((InetSocketAddress) socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()).getAddress()).toString().replace("/","");
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other answers return "ipaddr:port". This answer returns the IP address and removes the port number.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`getRemoteSocketAddress()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getRemoteSocketAddress()) instead.