# Get client ip from HttpServer

Tags: java

I need to know the clients ip addresses, Here is my cod

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Client ip is: " + server.getAddress().getAddress());
}
```

handler:

```
    public static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {

    t.getRemoteAddress().getAddress(); // t is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:
    }
}
```

Result:
`Client ip is: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`

Why i cant get real clients ip?

Comment: `5326` would be the port number, not the ip address.

Comment: @vandale My means that any other number except `0:0:0:0:0`

Comment: How would `server.getAddress()` return a client address ? Seems logical that this would return the address the server's is bound to. You should rather check what happens when a client connects...

Comment: @GPI So, How can i get clients ip?

Comment: i think you are running the client and server locally, try to run client in a separate computer

Comment: @Kerppag bt i have just one computer now!

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840420/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-client-connected-to-server)

Comment: as @GPI said you are getting the ip of the server

Comment: @Kerppag But i have not `getRemoteSocketAddress()` method

Comment: read [this](http://www.gnome.eu/Dwarf/doc/http/api/SK/gnome/dwarf/http/HTTPHandler.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can use `servletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` to get the client’s IP address that’s accessing your web-app. But, if user is behind a proxy server or access your web server through a load balancer (for example, in cloud hosting), the above code snippet will get the IP address of the proxy server or load balancer server, not the original IP address of a client.

Hence you should should get the IP address of the request’s HTTP header “X-Forwarded-For (XFF)“

```
 String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
   if (ipAddress == null) {  
       ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
   }
```

This snippet is taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/), as the explanation is best and needs no editing.
For more elaborate solution you can refer to answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client) . Especially the one by user- basZero.

Comment: Should i refuse using of `HttpServer` and start coding with `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` Objects?

Comment: Sorry but where did servletRequest come from?

Answer (score -2):

```
InetAddress address = server.getAddress().getAddress();
System.out.println("Client ip is: " +  address.getHostAddress());
```

This code above should give you the address. If you still get 0s for the IP, then there could be some permission issues.